# IF formula returning 0 or 1 depending on values in 3 cells?

Tags: excel, if-statement, excel-formula

I'm a beginner in Excel and I've been trying to make an `IF` formula  that will return 0 or 1 if certain conditions are met.

The formula in A3 must look at

- A1 to see if A1=1111
- A2 to see if A2=21,00
- A2 to see if A2=24,00.

So, if A1=1111 and A2=21,00 or 24,00 the result in A3 must be 1, but if A1=1111 and A2 is any other value, A3 must be 0.
 LE: If in other rows the value is 1112 the formula should return 1.

Comment: what if `A1<>1111`? `1` returns only in case `A1=1111 and A2=21,00 or 24,00` and for all other cases formula should return `0`?

Comment: Just tested on my table using Raystafarians formula. If A1<>1111 formula should return 1. Using the provided formula if A1=1112 the result is 0. I have failed to take this into consideration

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, use `and` as well as `or` -

<s>`=IF(AND(A1=1111,OR(A2=21,A2=24))=TRUE,1,0)`</s>

Per comments, to add more arguments, just expand the first test for the `and` with an `or` -

`=IF(AND(OR(B3=1111,B3=1112,B3=1113,B3=5555),OR(C3=21,C3=22.4))=TRUE,1,0)`

#### update

`=IF(B3<>1111,1,IF(AND(B3=1111,OR(C3=21,C3=22.4))=TRUE,1,0))`

Comment: Thanks for the help. I was close but didn`t take into consideration the A1<>1111 in the other rows like simco asked above. Is it posible to alter the formula so on the rows are =/=1111 the result will be 1?

Comment: @Andrei In that case, why test A1 at all? `=IF(OR(A2=21,A2=24)=TRUE,1,0)`

Comment: I have a large table that just got a new entry in the form of a new material. The formula that I`m already working with must look at the result in A3 and multiply it with the value (*0 to ignore and give a 0 overall result or *1 to keep the result). The formula that I have requested must tell me if the 1111 material has 21 or 24 tons it`s OK. If it has 2 tons or any other value it`s not. What you provided is perfect for the rows where the material is 1111 and the quantity is correct, but applied to the whole table it returns 0 to 1112 / 1113 and other materials.

Comment: You'll need to edit the formula and define all the materials e.g. `=IF(AND(OR(A1=1111,A1=1112,A1=1113),OR(A2=21,A2=24))=TRUE,1,0)`

Comment: Used it on my table and it still returns 0 on other materials (EX: material 1112 with 20 tons). The formula is: =IF(AND(OR(B3=1111,B3=1112,B3=1113,B3=5555),OR(C3=21,C3=22.4))=TRUE,1,0). Where B3 is the A1 in the OP and C3 is the A2

Comment: That formula works for me. Make sure there are no extra spaces and that they are formatted as numbers. If they aren't numbers you'll need to use `"1112"` and the like.

Comment: It works for material 1111 with the correct quantity (21 or 22.4) so the formula must have a problem with the other materials, for 1111 it returns 1 like it should. [link](http://picpaste.com/example.jpg)

Comment: This is the formula I'm using with no problems `=IF(AND(OR(B3=1111,B3=1112,B3=1113,B3=5555),OR(C3=21,C3=22.4))=TRUE,1,0)`

Comment: I think the problem is having 1111 in the same place as 1112 and the rest. For the other materials in B it still returns 0 in my table. Did you see the attached link in the previous post? I think it could clarify my problem.

Comment: @Andrei I see it, but I cannot reproduce it. My answer shows the formula and a chart that I used it on.

Comment: That`s OK. I`ll try sending someone the .xlsx and maybe I`ll figure something out. Thanks for your time and help.

Comment: Just seen your pic above. Try 8 tons instead of 21 on a 5555 row and it will return 0.

Comment: @Andrei 8 tons isn't a valid response, only 21 and 22.4. It *should* be 0.

Comment: That`s my problem. For any material beside 1111 the formula should return 1 regardless of the quantity.

Comment: =IF(B3<>1111,1,IF(AND(B3=1111,OR(C3=21,C3=22.4))=TRUE,1,0)) is the answer. Thanks and I owe you a beer. Case closed.